# Importing CSV into postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV and keep running into errors most recently:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY locations, line 1, column ext: ""
```

I'm still new to this, but from what I can tell it seems like it's not using `null` for any of the blank integer columns. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are a few lines from the CSV:

```
1 STOP ELECTRONICS CENTER,1100 CONEY ISLAND AVENUE,BROOKLYN,NY,11230,USA,7182491201,,,,
1 STOP FURNITURE WAREHOUSE,9050 KENMAR DR.,SAN DIEGO,CA,92121,USA,8582719400,,,,
309 OFFICE FURNITURE,1711 BETHLEHEM PARK,HATFIELD,PA,19440,USA,2158223333,,,,
"A & W OFFICE SUPPLY & DESIGN, INC.",10653 DUTCHTOWN ROAD,KNOXVILLE,TN,37932,USA,8656758532,,,,
```

Here is the COPY command I'm using:

```
COPY locations(name, address, city, province, postal_code, country, phone, ext, phone_alt, ext_alt, url) FROM '/Volumes/Data/Users/me/Dealers.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',',  NULL 'NULL');
```

Here is my locations table:

```
                                      Table "public.locations"
   Column    |            Type             |                       Modifiers                        
-------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     | not null default nextval('locations_id_seq'::regclass)
 name        | character varying(255)      | 
 address     | character varying(255)      | 
 city        | character varying(255)      | 
 province    | character varying(255)      | 
 postal_code | character varying(255)      | 
 country     | character varying(255)      | 
 phone       | bigint                      | 
 ext         | bigint                      | 
 phone_alt   | bigint                      | 
 ext_alt     | bigint                      | 
 latitude    | double precision            | 
 longitude   | double precision            | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null
 url         | character varying(255)      | 
Indexes:
    "locations_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the 'NULL'

COPY locations(name, address, city, province, postal_code, country, phone, ext, phone_alt, ext_alt, url) FROM '/Volumes/Data/Users/me/Dealers.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);

Comment: I tried that and got a different error: `ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 1 STOP ELECTRONICS CENTER...`. I assumed that, because I listed the columns, the data from the CSV would only be mapped to those specified and in that order. Is there a way to omit those?

Comment: Actually, I guess because they are `not null` is there an automatically generate a `created_at` and `updated_at`?

Comment: I just ended up adding a timestamp to the CSV. So the final working outcome was: `COPY locations(name, address, city, province, postal_code, country, phone, ext, phone_alt, ext_alt, created_at, updated_at, url) FROM '/Volumes/Data/Users/me/Dealers.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);`